# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on Maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, microservices

We have a set of Spring Boot applications organized as microservices running successfully for a few months. We used Sprig Boot 1.3.3.

Now we have a problem with maven build process switching to Spring Boot 1.4.2. We are developing microservice based software architecture. We have **core.common** service which is referenced by other services using dependecies like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>core.common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This service is responsible for providing common classes and methods needed to each of other services.

We also use separate service (**root.service**) to build **all other services** and to package them into `jar` files. This is the part of `pom.xml` from that **root.service**:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>../core.adminservice</module>
        <module>../core.locationservice</module>
        <module>../core.reportservice</module>
        <module>../core.userservice</module>
        <module>../core.notificationservice</module>
        <module>../core.trackingservice</module>
        <module>../core.mappingservice</module>
        <module>../core.common</module>
    </modules>
```

Until switched to Spring Boot 1.4.2 version we were able to do `mvn clean install` over **root.service** to test and build the rest of the services from **modules** specification.

After switching to Spring Boot 1.4.2 version, when I try to execute `mvn clean install` in **root.service** I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Exception message says that none of the services form **modules** specification cannot find any of classes from **core.common** service used in particular service from **modules**.
When I try to run `mvn compile` or `mvn test` everything runs just fine and I get successful builds and tests. When I try to run services from **eclipse** also everything is just fine.

Do you have any ideas? Please help.

**EDIT**
Full stack trace for one use case:

```
Running com.blockpeek.core.adminservice.tests.services.AdminServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.blockpeek.core.adminservice.tests.services.AdminServiceTest
initializationError(com.blockpeek.core.adminservice.tests.services.AdminServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/blockpeek/core/common/services/AbstractCRUDService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blockpeek.core.common.services.AbstractCRUDService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Maven Version:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

**EDIT 2:** This is what I get if i run `mvn -e clean install`:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]                                                                                                                             
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (def
ult-compile) on project core.adminservice: Compilation failure                                                                                  
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)                                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)                                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)                                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)                             
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)                              
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)                
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)                                              
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)                                                                       
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)                                                                       
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)                                                                         
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)                                                                             
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)                                                                              
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)                                                                                
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                          
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                        
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)                                                                                     
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)                                                  
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)                                                          
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)                                                
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)                                                            
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure                                                    
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1029)                                        
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:137)                                                         
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)                                    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)                                                      
        ... 20 more                                                                                                                             
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                         
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.                                                                          
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                         
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:                                       
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException                                                          
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                         
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command                                                                
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :core.adminservice
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: @Tunaki Why you put it as off-topic? What is the problem with the question? The cutting edge technology is used for software architecture development, and the the widest used open source framework is used for development. This question may be related to unknown issues in Spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE also.

Comment: I solved this by switching to Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because of the changes made in strucutre of the jar file from Spring Boot 1.4: [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes)

> The layout of executable jars has changed. If you are using Spring
>   Boot’s Maven, Gradle, or Ant support to build your application this
>   change will not affect you. If you are building an executable archive
>   yourself, please be aware that an application’s dependencies are now
>   packaged in BOOT-INF/lib rather than lib, and an application’s own
>   classes are now packaged in BOOT-INF/classes rather than the root of
>   the jar.